# rpm package libpng12-1.2.50-10.el7.x86_64 is missing . server is deployed using puppet

Tags: centos, puppet

I have two remote sites on which i have CentOS 7.4 based servers. I have deployed the servers using puppet and both sites have same configuration. On one site the one of my server is missing this  libpng12-1.2.50-10.el7.x86_64 package while the other site has this package. 
Do we have any way to find out actually which rpm is missing which leads to missing
libpng12-1.2.50-10.el7.x86_64

Answer (score 1):

You can search the rpm binary and source on

> https://centos.pkgs.org

This site shows packages with requirements and you can check the requirements of a rpm package if installed on your server

```
rpm -qa | grep "require rpm packages"
```

For example:
one of the  required packages of ibpng12-1.2.50-10.el7.x86_64 is

> glibc-core-2.30-alt1.x86_64.rpm

To check for that package do:

```
 rpm -qa | grep "glibc-core-2.30-alt1.x86_64.rpm"
```

Comment: “rpm -qa” will not return package names ending with .rpm. You can just run “rpm -q glibc-core” if you want to see if that packag is installed and what version/release it is. I’m not sure how your post is an answer though. You should use yum to find out what packages are available, not pkgs.org.

Answer (score 1):

That is the name of the rpm. If you run this command, you'll see it:

```
yum list available | grep libpng12
```

One of the results will be:

```
libpng12.x86_64                           1.2.50-10.el7                  base
```

You can then install with with:

```
yum install libpng12
```

Comment: Yes i have installed it manually but i need to know how this rpm is not installed

Comment: i need to know the dependent rpm

Comment: Didn't @jaberansariali answer that already?

Comment: @ NiksaKovacevik What do you mean by "I need to know how this rpm is not installed?" The package that you are referring to is the name of the rpm. If you already installed it then what's the problem?

Comment: It’s possible that your puppet manifest is missing libpng12 or any packages that might require libpng12. You could use “yum history” to look at recent transactions to see when it might have been installed. You can also just run “yum remove libpng12” (and then say no to remove) to see what depends on it and is installed.